# Matlab returns the function only

Tags: matlab

```
syms h v t g
g = 10;

eqn1 = h==(v.^2 * (sin(t)).^2)/2*g;

t=1;
v=10;

vpasolve(eqn1,h)
```

I want to solve this equation for values inside a matrix. but before that I wanted to test this if it is working correctly. however after the definition of **eqn1**, the values I assign to the variables **v,t** doesn't seem to get by when I use **vpasolve**. How do I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the function [subs](https://ch.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/subs.html).
You have two options. You can simply do this:

```
t=1;
v=10;
vpasolve(subs(eqn1),h)
```

But I think the following is more readable and less prone to errors:

```
vpasolve(subs(eqn1,[t,v],[1,10]),h)
```